# edge looping irregular vertical edges

Tags: modeling, uv

i want to UVMap this object imported from an obj file

[image]

wich is basically a cylinder, so i have seams marked top and down round faces,
but for the vertical edge loop it's more difficult since there is no straight edge from the top to the bottom .

here a close look on a part of the model in edit mode that describe the problem

[image]

as you can see it's no possible to edge loop vertically, at least with the regular way .

another option i have tested is to use the knife tool to make a cut from the top to the bottom of the model , but it didn't work

here a close look of the knife tool operation
[image]

as you can see it don't create all the vertical edges ..

so yeah, any idea or help is welcome, thanks .

here the blend file if someone want to check this out
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1s8jz0r5x0kBLs-voiwJ5aBCs41xmDEA6)

Comment: The geometry doesn't even look connected. Might be easier to model this again with the obj import as reference rather than fixing the geometry and topology.

Comment: i could do that or try to fix the geometry in each section , but since i have a lot of models like this one i want to find a better option

Comment: Your obj model is a true hoax, the best solution you can develop is to do it yourself, it is not a complex model or requires great knowledge, and you can take that piece of anything as a reference, instead of wanting to repair something that will take you more time